# how to read a single files in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

so i want to read the roles of my users, i know how to read collection and document,but how to read a field from the documents?

this what i've been trying,

```
    @override
  void readRole(){
    final path = APIPath.role(uid);
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    snapshots.listen((snapshot) { snapshot.docs.forEach((snapshot) => print(snapshot.data()));
    });
  }
```

```
static String role (String uid) => 'users/$uid';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doc.data() has type of Map<String, dynamic> , meaning Json.
so you could try something like this:

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
final String role = data['role'];
```

But the best way would be to create a user entity and use Json_serializable: https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable
and convert the firestore data object to your user entity;

But by checking your role() function, i am not sure to understand it correctly, user's role is just the string 'users/$uid' ?

Comment: i already get it, thanks for the help tho. :D